# Как посчитать количество за день

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть скрипт xCharts для реализации графика [ссылка на исходники](http://sitear.ru/material/jquery-xcharts-grafiki-sozdayte-krasivye-grafiki). В данном примере база mysql устроена немного по другому чем у меня, там вручную записано общее кол-во за день. Мне же нужно чтобы скрипт считал общее количество записей на каждый день. Сам код:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Set up the ORM library
require_once('setup.php');

if (isset($_GET['start']) AND isset($_GET['end'])) {

    $start = $_GET['start'];
    $end = $_GET['end'];
    $data = array();

    // Select the results with Idiorm
    $results = ORM::for_table('sync')
            ->where_gte('date', $start)
            ->where_lte('date', $end)
            ->order_by_desc('url')
            ->find_array();         

    // Build a new array with the data
    foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key]['label'] = $value['date'];
        $data[$key]['value'] = $value['url']; // здесь нужно выводить общее количество за каждый день
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

на данный момент работает так:

```
[{"label":"2017-10-24","value":"http://ссылка"},{"label":"2017-10-25","value":"http://ссылка"},{"label":"2017-10-25","value":"http://ссылка"},{"label":"2017-10-22","value":"http://ссылка"},{"label":"2017-10-22","value":"http://ссылка"},{"label":"2017-10-25","value":"http://ссылка"},{"label":"2017-10-24","value":"http://ссылка"},{"label":"2017-10-23","value":"http://ссылка"}]
```

должно быть так:

```
[{"label":"2017-10-22","value":"2"},{"label":"2017-10-23","value":"1"},{"label":"2017-10-24","value":"2"},{"label":"2017-10-25","value":"3"}]
```

Comment: ну так разбейте на массивы по датам и подсчитайте кол-во элементов в них, если я правильно Вас понял

Comment: в sql это бы решалось с помощью `count(*)` для получения количества и `group by date`  для группировки по дням. попробуйте поискать как это донести до вашей ORM. гугл говорит, что вот так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533080/laravel-eloquent-groupby-and-also-return-count-of-each-group